# GROUP BY WITH HAVING ( DISTINCT ) : PHP , MYSQL

Tags: mysql, count, group-by, sum, having

```
id | mid | pid | owgh | nwgh |
1    3      12    1.5    0.6
2    3      12    1.5    0.3
3    3      14    0.6    0.4
4    3      15    1.2    1.1
5    4      16    1.5    1.0
6    4      17    2.4    1.2 
7    3      19    3.0    1.4
```

From Above i want total count of mid AND SUM of nwgh with its resp. id ex: mid=3 or mid=4 
but with DISTINCT pid but please note sum of nwgh should not be DISTINCT

Hence my result will be as below :

```
mid  | countmid            |   totalnwgh
3      4 (DISTINCT value)      3.8 (no DISTINCT it take both value of pid =12)
4      2                       2.2
```

in above result mid = 3 have count 4 beause pid = 12 is repeated hence its DISTINCT **but nwgh should not be DISTINCT , its total count**

***what i have tried***

```
Select mid , COUNT(mid) as countmid  , SUM(nwgh) as totalnwgh from test where mid = 3
GROUP BY mid HAVING count(DISTINCT pid)
```

Comment: It is hard to guess what you want to have. What do you want to get for mid=3 and what for mid=4? Having is a constraint, not a select

Comment: @flaschenpost its group result for mid=3 and what for mid=4 resp. may be mid=5 will also have in list and so on ... in short below ex:
a  4   3.3 , b  3  4.5  , c 1 1.2 and so on on .....where a , b , c are mid in my case

Comment: so countmid=4 and totalnwgh = 3.8 is the answer you want to have, both nwgh of pid=12 should be summed?

Comment: yes your right ,....pid = 12 is repeated hence its DISTINCT which  countmid=4 but its nwgh is not DISTINCT which is  totalnwgh = 3.8

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understand what you want, you just have to do a **distinct** in your **COUNT**.

You can try this :

```
SELECT mid , 
    COUNT(distinct pid) as countmid  , 
    SUM(nwgh) as totalnwgh 
FROM test 
GROUP BY mid
```

Try this sqlfiddle if you want : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/45e68/2

Comment: woh ..it was so simple ... i was trying COUNT(mid) as countmid instead of COUNT(distinct pid) as countmid ...thanks ...its work perfect ...

Comment: hey how i can get DISTINCT owgh  BUT IT SHOULD BE GROUP BY pid  WITH ABOVE YOUR QUERY ....

Comment: PLEASE SEE : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32536393/2-group-by-with-distinct-php-myql

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
SELECT a.`mid`, a.cnt AS countmid, b.s AS totalnwgh
FROM
    (SELECT `mid`, COUNT(DISTINCT pid) AS cnt FROM test GROUP BY 1) AS a INNER JOIN
    (SELECT `mid`, SUM(nwgh) AS s FROM test GROUP BY 1) b ON a.mid=b.mid
```

Comment: why should you introduce two complete subselects? This looks twice as slow as coytech's answer.

Comment: i agree, my solution may be better suited when using two different tables