# 2 GROUP BY WITH DISTINCT, SUM , COUNT: PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, count, group-by, sum

Ref : [GROUP BY WITH HAVING ( DISTINCT ) : PHP , MYSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32066097/group-by-with-having-distinct-php-mysql)

I got answer (thanks @coytech) but I need one more column in it:

as per:

```
id | mid | pid | owgh | nwgh |
1    3      12    1.5    0.6
2    3      12    1.5    0.3
3    3      14    0.6    0.4
4    3      15    1.2    1.1
5    4      16    1.5    1.0
6    4      17    2.4    1.2 
7    3      19    3.0    1.4
```

I got answer

> Select mid , 
>         COUNT(distinct pid) as cpid  , 
>         SUM(nwgh) as totalnwgh  from test  GROUP BY mid

sqlfiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/45e68/2

```
mid  cpid       totalnwgh
3      4          3.8
4      2          2.2
```

But above I need one more column that's as below : **totowgh**

```
mid cpid        totalnwgh  totowgh
3      4          3.8        6.3 (DISTINCT value as per pid column)
4      2          2.2        3.9
```

where totowgh = 6.3 come by DISTINCT value as per pid column

That's mid = 3 has count 5 but distinct pid  = 4 for mid=3 same way "distinct" owgh = 6.3 for mid=3 and distinct pid.

As pid=12 is count 1 time hence,

1.5 + 0.6 + 1.2 + 3 = 6.3 ( please not this is as per DISTINCT value of pid )

Please note : i need owgh value as per distinct pid or group by pid .. because if i replace value of owgh 0.6 with 1.5 then it will be 5.7 instead of 7.2 but value of owgh 0.6 belong to pid = 14 and not pid = 12 hence totalcount of owgh change ...but i need is 7.2

SEE WHAT I MEANS  : [sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2a53c/6](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2a53c/6)

Comment: From where did you get that `6.3` and as per your given table the count of `countmid` is `5` and not `4`. Please be specific what you want to achieve over here

Comment: at uchiha i think u havent read properly ... i have mention properly above MYSQL QUERY "  COUNT(distinct pid) as countmid " thats " distinct  pid " hence is 4 not 5 , same way i need distinct owgh but with distinct  pid, thats mid = 3 have owgh = 7.8 but i need owgh as distinct  pid hence pid = 12 is count as one  hence i get 6.3

Comment: please see how i got 6.3

Comment: @Uchiha ,, YOU Deleted your answer ? ... what happen ..its is possible ? or not...please let me know

Comment: any one here ? ..please help me

Comment: Yes it is possible but my answer is not the correct one thats why I've deleted it

Comment: ohh so sir you putting new answer ? ..please help me...u should i have edited there itself ...

Comment: What if the value of `owgh` is one time `1.5` and one time `1.4` for `mid = 3` and `pid = 12`? Which value should be chosen to calculate with?

Comment: good question sir ....then both should be taken ...as my first preference is to see distinct value for owgh for pid = 12 .. repeated value should be seen with distinct pid..as said above ... owgh value 1.5 may again repeat in pid=14 then its should be treated different as its belong to two different pid

Comment: sir its clear ? .... please help me

Answer (score 0):

OK, per your followup comment this is what I came up with. First get the grouping of the distinct `owgh` and then perform a `JOIN` with main query. See a demo fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a56e4/1

```
SELECT t.`mid` , 
COUNT(distinct t.`pid`) AS countmid , 
SUM(t.`nwgh`) AS totalnwgh,
xx.`totowgh`
FROM test t JOIN (
select mid, sum(owgh) as totowgh 
from (
select distinct mid, owgh from test) x
group by mid) xx ON t.`mid` = xx.`mid`
GROUP BY t.`mid`;
```

It will result in

```
mid     countmid    totalnwgh   totowgh
3          4           3.8        6.3
4          2           2.2        3.9
```

Comment: rahul please see update question , what i need is group by mid and group by pid ... where group by mid is for whole QUERY and group by pid ( or you can say distinct pid ) is for  distinct owgh

Comment: please see how i have got 6.3

Comment: your sum will count 1.5 + 1.5 + 0.6 + 1.2 + 3.0 = 7.8 , but i need .................. 1.5 +0.6 + 1.2 +3.0 = 6.3 which is as per distinct pid column with group by mid

Comment: rahul you der ? ... please see my update question ..please help me

Comment: @user3209031, See edited query in answer as well as the fiddle link. Hope this is what you are looking for.